# How to click on an element and then use that to change another element

Tags: python, pygame

I'm still a noob to python and now im just getting started with my GUI's. Right now I have a bunch of elements on a screen, and I want to know how I can register a click on one element, and then use that to change both the element that was clicked on and another element. To put it into context, I'm making a light switch. I'll post the code I have so far as it isn't too chunky.

```
#Import pygame lib
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

#Load images
switchOn = pygame.image.load("resources/img/switchOn.png")
switchOff = pygame.image.load("resources/img/switchOff.png")
bulbOn = pygame.image.load("resources/img/bulbOn.png")
bulbOff = pygame.image.load("resources/img/bulbOff.png")

#Loop
while 1:
    #clear screen before drawing again
    screen.fill(0)
    #draw the screen elements
    screen.blit(bulbOff, (50,50))
    screen.blit(switchOff, (300,250))
    #update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    #loop the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #check if event is X button
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To register a click on, say, a button, you need to use the pygame.Rect.collidepoint (http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) and check if the current mouse position is within the rectangle of our button.

In pseudo code:

```
check for events
    if event is mouseclick
        if button.rect.collidepoint(button, mouse_pos)
            # player clicked, so...
            do something
```

Creating a clickable button is not much trouble, to be honest, but it might be a bit rough if you're new at Python and PyGame.